# PHP curl_exec return

Tags: php, php-curl

I am using this `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1` in my code that's return a result if success.

My question is:

The curl_exec() will return a result if I get a response with status != 200 ? like 400 and a message ? or in this case just FALSE ?

Comment: Please answer your own question rather that adding a note to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the manual carefuly. The answer is there.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php

*Note that response status codes which indicate errors (such as 404 Not found) are not regarded as failure. curl_getinfo() can be used to check for these.*